# American Mathematical Monthly reprints, as opposed to preprints, on the arXiv

Tags: arxiv, reprint

The arXiv is for preprints, but may also be used to disseminate reprints.

What considerations bear upon the advisability of putting a reprint from the *American Mathematical Monthly* there? In particular:

- Is it permissible under copyright law and might that depend on how long it's been since publication? Monthly articles of a certain age (three years or more maybe?) are available through jstor(dot)org, I presume with the consent of whoever owns the rights, so I would guess that after that time it is permissible?
- Does it get substantially more attention for the article than it gets from jstor(dot)org and from library subscriptions to the *Monthly* and from other subscriptions? Here it seems that anyone with internet access can see it, whereas with jstor(dot)org you need an account on the web site of a library that subscribes. One could post a link to it here.

Comment: IANAL but I am pretty sure that would violate copyright. An article in the Monthly will be found as easily there legally as on arXiv by any reasonable search strategy. There are probably workarounds for folks who don't have access to jstor. This is not one.

Comment: Whether it’s permitted or not would depend on what the copyright transfer form you sign says.

Comment: @EthanBolker : Whether it would violate copyright would depend on whether the _Monthly_ has a policy of permitting such things.

Comment: Policies vary by journal and some let you pick among different policies for a fee.

Comment: I now have an email from the Editor-Elect saying she will check with the Managing Editor and Publishing Manager who are out until January 3.

Answer (score 8):

The Monthly's [information for authors](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/AuthorInfo_Monthly.pdf) links to [Taylor and Francis's general policy](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/research-impact/sharing-versions-of-journal-articles/) on this point.  If by "reprint" you mean the VOR (version of record) then no you can't post it to the arxiv.  You can, however, post the AOM (author original manuscript) to the arxiv.

Comment: I was not aware until after I posted this that a commercial publisher owned the rights to this. Some mathematicians have realized that certain conflicts between the interests of commercial publishers and those of academia make it better to do things in other ways that that, and so it seems to me one should be wary of such an arrangement. Seemingly few mathematicians have realized this is part of a broader problem of certain kinds of corruption in academia. One other small symptom is the widespread practice of . . . . . .

Comment: . . . . encouraging vast numbers of students to take calculus who have earned good grades in the prerequisite course but who are known not to have understood the prerequisite subject matter in a way that is needed to learn first-year calculus in the way contemplated by textbooks and curricula. Instead they just learn algorithms like (d/dx)x^n = nx^{n-1} without ever suspecting that learning mathematics consists of something other than learning to apply memorized algorithms. Mathematicians see that that is all they learn and attribute it to an unfortunate lack of . . . . . . . .

Comment: . . . . . . ability of most of the students, but seemingly fail to see that the system encourages lack of ability because it is a good strategy for doing what the students want to do, which is _not_ learning the subject, but getting grades. A few places like the University of Toronto and Macalester College and some of the liberal arts colleges in western Massachusetts are dealing with this issue to some extent. but many many professors of mathematics are blind to it. And probably some want to keep it that way just to rake in paychecks for phony teaching. And some administrators . . . . . .

Comment: It’s *owned* by the MAA who *contracts* to Taylor and Francis for publishing.  Acta and Compositio have similar arrangements.  This is much better than it being owned by a publisher.

Comment: . . . . . want to keep it that way in order to rake in the tuition money.

Comment: If it is owned by MAA who contracts with that company, then why does that company own the rights?

Comment: If it is owned by MAA who contracts with that company, then why does that company own the rights?

Comment: I don’t think that company does own the rights.  I think the MAA does.

Comment: But you said there is a Taylor & Francis policy upon which this depends, rather than an MAA policy.

Comment: Because the MAA chose it that way, they could change their minds. Institut Mittag-Leffler switched from Springer to International Press for publication of Acta and then put their whole back catalog online for free.  Which they could do because they owned it.

Comment: Have you read the contract? Is it publicly available?